# How to handle errors for conditionally rendered form fields - React Hook Form & Zod

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, zod

I want to implement error handling in such a manner that if a form is currently being rendered, meaning that it's been selected from the mode of payment options, then an error should be displayed in case the user attempts to submit the form when there's an error. But if a form is not currently displayed, then an error should not be thrown for the form field when the user attempts to submit the form after populating another rendered form field.

With my current implementation, I'm getting an error in `formState.errors` for the form fields that are not conditionally displayed.

What I've tried:

- using `RHF` `clearErrors` but according to the docs, it doesn't affect validation rules or isValid formState.
- discriminated union types without success

Code:

Form Schema:

```
const FormSchema = z.object({
  modeOfPayment: z.string().nonempty({ message: "Please select an option" }),
  tillNumber: z.string().min(1, { message: "Please provide a value" }),
  paybillNumber: z
    .string()
    .min(1, { message: "Please provide a value" })
    .max(8, { message: "Please enter a valid paybill number" }),
  accountNumber: z
    .string()
    .min(1, { message: "Please provide a value" })
    .max(20, { message: "Please enter a valid account number" }),
});
```

`select` component for Mode of payment

```
          <div>
            <h2>
              Mode of Payment
              <span className="text-red-700 ml-1">*</span>
            </h2>
            <select
              {...register("modeOfPayment", {
                onChange: (e) => {
                  console.log("MODEOFPAYMENT EVENT", e);
                  setSelectedPaymentMode(e.target.value);
                },
              })}
              className={
              {*/ ... /*}
              }
            >
              <option value="" disabled={true}>
                Choose a mode of payment
              </option>
              <option value="Mpesa Buy Goods">Mpesa Buy Goods</option>
              <option value="Mpesa Paybill">Mpesa Paybill</option>
            </select>
            {errors?.modeOfPayment?.message && (
              <p className=" text-red-700 mt-1">
                {errors.modeOfPayment.message}
              </p>
            )}
          </div>
```

'Mpesa Buy Goods'

```
          {selectedPaymentMode === "Mpesa Buy Goods" && (
            <div>
              <h2>
                Enter till number
                <span className="text-red-700 ml-1">*</span>
              </h2>
              <input
                {...restTillNumber}
                ref={(e) => {
                  tillNoRef(e);
                  tillNumberRef.current = e;
                  console.log("ref event (tillNumber): ", e);
                }}
                type="text"
                className={
                {/* ... */}
                }
              />
              {errors?.tillNumber?.message && (
                <p className=" text-red-700 mt-1">
                  {errors.tillNumber.message}
                </p>
              )}
            </div>
          )}
```

'Mpesa Paybill'

```
          {selectedPaymentMode === "Mpesa Paybill" && (
            <div>
              <div>
                <h2 className="font-semibold mb-1">
                  Enter Paybill number
                  <span className="text-red-700 ml-1">*</span>
                </h2>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  {...restPaybillNumber}
                  ref={(e) => {
                    paybillNoRef(e);
                    paybillNumberRef.current = e;
                    console.log("ref event (paybillNumber): ", e);
                  }}
                  className={
                  {/* ... */}
                   }
                />
                {errors?.paybillNumber?.message && (
                  <p className="text-red-700 mt-1">
                    {errors.paybillNumber.message}
                  </p>
                )}
              </div>
              <div>
                <h2>
                  Account number
                  <span className="text-red-700 ml-1">*</span>
                </h2>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  {...restAccountNumber}
                  ref={(e) => {
                    accountNoRef(e);
                    accountNumberRef.current = e;
                  }}
                  className={
                  {/* ... */}
                  }
                />
                {errors?.accountNumber?.message && (
                  <p className="text-red-700 mt-1">
                    {errors.accountNumber.message}
                  </p>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
```

handle selected payment mode

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedPaymentMode === "Mpesa Paybill") {
      reset({ tillNumber: "" });
      clearErrors("tillNumber");
    }
    if (selectedPaymentMode === "Mpesa Buy Goods") {
      reset({ paybillNumber: "", accountNumber: "" });
      clearErrors(["paybillNumber", "accountNumber"]);
    }
  }, [selectedPaymentMode]);
```

Create refs for conditionally rendered form fields

```
  const tillNumberRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
  const paybillNumberRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
  const accountNumberRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
  const modeOfPaymentRef = useRef<HTMLSelectElement | null>(null);

  const { ref: tillNoRef, ...restTillNumber } = register("tillNumber");
  const { ref: paybillNoRef, ...restPaybillNumber } = register("paybillNumber");
  const { ref: accountNoRef, ...restAccountNumber } = register("accountNumber");
```